# How do I get a the list that split() didn't return in VIM?s

Tags: vim

In VIM, if I do a `:echo split('abcd123ef4ghij56k', '\d\+')`, the representation of the list `[abcd', 'ef', 'ghij', 'k']` is printed. But I am looking for a behaviour that prints what split() did not return, in this case: `['123', '4', '56']`.

Of course, in a simple example like here, I could change the pattern to `\D\+` in order to get what I want. Yet, this is not what I am after because the pattern is an argument in a function and I think I don't know how to *opposite* the pattern.

Here's a function that returns such a list for an expression:

```
function! MatchMultiplePatterns(txt, re) 

  let l:result = []

  let l:pos = match(a:txt, a:re)

  while l:pos != -1

        let l:matchedString = matchstr(a:txt, a:re, l:pos)
        let l:result += [l:matchedString]

        let l:pos = match(a:txt, a:re, l:pos + strlen(l:matchedString))

  endwhile

  return l:result

endfunction
```

But I believe this should be possible without a `while`-loop and calling match() twice.

Comment: So you want to get all the text that matches a pattern?

Comment: Yes, all, and only, the text that matches a pattern, as a list with one item for each match.

Comment: "oppositie of split()" is a weird way to describe this. I think most would say that the "opposite" of `split()` is `join()`. Clarifying your title may yield better answers.

Comment: @Laurence, thanks to point that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried to use negative patterns with no luck (I always have troubles with their logic).
Anyway. If you really wish to have something short, we can always have a one-liner based on several calls to substitute that replaces what is in between two occurrences of the pattern by '#', and then finally split on '#'

Otherwise, I'd use match() and matchend() + the_full_string[begin:end] to implement the function you have implemented.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is a good solution in the general case, but…

```
:echo split('abcd123ef4ghij56k', '\d\zs\ze\D\|\D\zs\ze\d')
['abcd', '123', 'ef', '4', 'ghij', '56', 'k']
:echo split('abcd123ef4ghij56k', '\d\@<=\D\@=\|\D\@<=\d\@=')
['abcd', '123', 'ef', '4', 'ghij', '56', 'k']
```

splits on digit-to-nondigit and nondigit-to-digit boundaries.

Comment: As the OP said, the real pattern is not `\d`. In that case, `\D\+` would have been the perfect parameter for `split()`. Try with something we don't have a clear inverse, like `foo`, or even `fo*` for instance.